# Как с помощью radio button сменить изображения на сайте

Tags: php, css

Landing page на wordpress http://di-tech.kiev.ua

На сайте 6 отдельных блоков с изображениями. Нужно сделать две кнопки с цветом товара, при клике на кнопку будут меняться картинки во всех блоках (на выбранный цвет).

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/5264#5264)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
  $(".block").css({"background": $(this).val()});

});
```

```css
.block{
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   background-color: green; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="radio"  value="red" name="radioButton" id="radioButton1">1 
<input type="radio" value="black" name="radioButton" id="radioButton2">2

<div class="block">
</div>
```

Comment: На странице 6 блоков с разными картинками в которых нужно заменить картинки при выборе цвета.

Как передать инфу в каждый блок, что бы в нём изменилась картинка.


Была мысль сделать для каждого блока свой класс, назвать картинки с хвостами "-black" и "-gray"  и подставлять в скрипте. Как правильно написать $(".block").css({"background": "url(http://di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/img" $(this).val()});

Comment: Код рабочий, за него вам спасибо!

Мне в value нужно передать часть ссылки на картинку.

$(".block").css({"background": "url(di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/img-"; $(this).val()});
value="grey.jpg"

Comment: да, изменения я не могу посмотреть.

Если в value вставить ссылку value="http://di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/radiobutton-black.jpg", то не работает.

Comment: 100% путь не верный :)

Comment: ))) Ну так наставьте на путь истинный

Answer (score 0):

Может так будет понятнее, что я хочу сделать ))

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
  $(".block").css({"background":"url(http://di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/radiobutton-"+ this val +")"});

});
```

```css
.block{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background: url(http://di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/radiobutton-black.jpg); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio"  value="black.jpg" name="radioButton" id="radioButton1">black 
<input type="radio" value="gray.jpg" name="radioButton" id="radioButton2">gray

<div class="block">
</div>
```

Comment: Сделайте вот так, укажите полный путь до картинок, а имена вытаскиваете из value  $().css({"":"url(http://site.com/wp-content/...../radiobutton-"+ this val +") });

Comment: Наставляю)  Откройте картинку в браузере по полному пути, как откроется возьмите названия этой картинки и вставьте в value=""  потом возьмите ссылку и вставьте её в url(""); естественно без названия :)  потом кликайте по тому radio button с тем value  если вдруг не сработает смотрите консоль а потом проверяйте путь, так же не забывайте чистить кэш ctl+f5

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решён. Спасибо за помощь!

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
  $(".sovmestimost").css({"background":"url(http://di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/sovmestimost-"+ $(this).val() +")"});
  $(".dvametra").css({"background":"url(http://di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/dvametra-"+ $(this).val() +")"});

});
```

```css
.sovmestimost{
  width:550px;
   height:550px;
   background: url(http://di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/sovmestimost-black.jpg);
 }
 .dvametra{
  width:550px;
   height:550px;
   background: url(http://di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/dvametra-black.jpg);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio"  value="black.jpg" name="radioButton" id="radioButton1">black 
<input type="radio" value="gray.jpg" name="radioButton" id="radioButton2">gray

<div class="sovmestimost">
</div>

<div class="dvametra">
</div>
```